# Old subjective questions

Tags: discussion, old-questions

I've seen some old questions especially about programming language (feature) comparing but the answers mostly have a tendency to one side and lacking objectivity.

To give you an example: [Garbage Collection in C/C++ versus Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842737/garbage-collection-in-c-c-versus-java) (answers are not mentioning pros of a GC).

Will these questions stay as they are / Are the valid for Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not valid questions for SO.  Vote/flag to close them, if they're open, when you come across them.

If they have any content that is worth keeping around they shouldn't be deleted, so they'll still be there, although once closed no new answers will be able to be posted.  If there isn't any valuable content at all, the questions can simply be deleted entirely.

Answer (score -2):

I wouldn't bother doing anything about questions like the one you cited.  That one:

1. Is clearly stated,
2. Is about programming, and
3. Is specific enough to be answerable.

In addition, it has attracted no flags, spam answers, off-topic discussion, or close votes (except for the one placed on it three minutes ago, probably as a result of this meta discussion).

When I saw the question, I immediately thought of two things that were stated in the answers, namely that

> C++ doesn't have (built-in) garbage collection, but that doesn't mean you should let your dynamically allocated memory stay allocated forever. You can and should free it.

and

> Java doesn't automatically remove the object at the end of each loop. Instead it waits until there is a lot of garbage and then goes through and collects it. Java makes no guarantees about how long it will be before the object is collected.

It's a good question, with good answers and good information.  In short, we have bigger fish to fry.

Comment: As I said the answers are not mentioning the advantages of a garbage collector. The phrase you cited about the Java GC sounds more like a disadvantage than an advantage.

Comment: @JimmyT.: If you're worred about the word "advantage," then edit the question so that it no longer contains the word.  Ah, wait a minute... the question doesn't even have the words "advantages" or "disadvantages" in it.

Comment: The answer describes many advantages of the style of C++ but not the advantages of having a GC. It is also missing the cause why C++ in fact is missing a GC. If I included all this points in the answer I have to make a big edit. Is that desirable?

Comment: I would add your own answer, if you want to make those kinds of clarifications.

Comment: Will anyone see it after the other eight answers?

Comment: Adding an answer bumps the question.